# jQuery featured content slider problem with embedded flash youtube video, overflowing div

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, youtube

I created an ajax jQuery featured content slider that will automatically navigate through each tab.  Each tab has some basic html.

The one I used is this one:  http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

For some reason, when I embed a flash video in it, the flash video overflows the div.  It looks fine in Chrome and Safari but not the latest version of Firefox (3.6) on the PC.

Any suggestions?  Is it not handling overflow or z-indexes correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: What Flash version are you using`? Is your flash movie `wmode=transparent`?

Comment: this is the sample flash embed code from youtube, that I'm using:

<object width="480" height="295"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/riYcLMRV22M&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/riYcLMRV22M&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="295"></embed></object>

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention having set flash wmode to "opaque", flash only respects z-index when this is set